# How to calculate individual documents score BM25F score for each document?

Tags: python, ranking, information-retrieval, ranking-functions

I a trying to implement BM25F from scratch in Python.
Here is the simplified folumation of the BM25F:

[image]

However, after implementing it, I am getting the same score for all the documents in the collection.

After a careful inspection, the only intuition I can understand is that the formulation is considering the stream scores and not the individual document scores.

Which part of the formulation am I missing that considers the individual scores for each document?

I am trying consciously since last week to decode this without any luck, any help would be immensely appreciated!